# Scrollable table with hover content

Tags: html, css, html-table, position, overflow

I have a problem with a task which I have now written down in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/a1503080/pen/JZoNNq).

```
.content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
td:hover .content {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ffcce0;
  color: black;
  border: 4px solid #ffb3d1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

When I hover over the icon the content shows how it should but when I scroll down or to the side and hover again the same icon the position of the content moves away from the original position. In Mozilla it works fine! How do I fix this problem? It seems to be a bug from Chrome right? (if possible the solution should be without Javascript)

[image]
So if i scroll down or/and to the side and then hover over the green icon the content isn't showing underneath the icon. I can fix this by giving the td's position relative but then the content doesn't show when the icon is on the bottom or right side of the table. It kinda hides behind the table

Comment: Can you show us what the problem is with a picture/gif or explain it better? I see the message boxes showing up on hover, but I don't understand the *problem* with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the popup where you want by adding `position: relative;` to your td elements. This makes the position of the popup relative to the td.

However this will cause a problem for td elements that are along the bottom or right side of the table; they will be hidden within the scrolling div.

AFAIK the only way to solve that is through Javascript, which is why for example Bootstrap uses JS to position them. (Bootstrap uses the Popper.js library https://popper.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution: [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/SirExotic/pen/MXyMpE)

- I gave your `table` a `position: relative;` so that the `.content` element is relative to its parent (`table`).
- I also styled your `.content` in a way that it fits nicely under the `table` when hovered.

```
body {
  background-color: #ffe6e6;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
.table {
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}
.scroll {
 overflow-x: auto;
 overflow-y: auto;
 max-height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
}
.green{
  color: lime;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ffcce0;
  color: black;
  border: 4px solid #ffb3d1;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
td:hover .content {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i have also tried to give the td's position relative but then the bottom or right side green icons are hiding behind the table.

Comment: Unfortunately that is the problem with the table design. I updated my answer with a new suggestion; to put the content below the table so it is always visible and is always in the same place. Let me know what you think :)

Comment: Yeah since it is too difficult to have it under the icon i may use your suggestion if there isn't coming any other solutions :)

Comment: Thank you. If you really want to have the content message boxes under the hovered items, I would suggest to style the whole table differently. But that's up to you :)